# jsTree ajax loading indicator on select node (MVC 4.0)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jstree

I have a JStree (well, in fact, 3 trees. Don't say that too fast....) on my page. On this tree, I dynamically load nodes via Ajax, no problem here, the built in indicator works fine.
Now, when a node is selected, I load a list of items via an Ajax call to another method in the same controller and a partial view. This works just fine, too.

The thing is, I have not (yet) found a proper way to tell that second Ajax call to use a different indicator. What I have so far is

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.loadingIndicator').hide();           
    });

    $(document).ajaxSend(function() {
        $('.loadingIndicator').show();
    });

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
        $('.loadingIndicator').hide();
    });
```

but obviously, this indicator also show loading when the branches of the tree are loaded, which is confusing.

Thanks for any help,
Bernard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I ended up doing something very simple which I should have thought about before asking. I guess I am still intimidated by javascript/jquery...

Anyway, I created a global variable to use as flag, set it to one just before the proper ajax call, and transformed the previous ajaxSend function to be like this:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function () {
if (itemLoad === 1) {               
    $('#ListOfBooksHere').showLoading();
    itemLoad = 0;
}
```

});

Works perfectly.